# Correct way to dispose memory mapped files in C#

Tags: c#, dispose, memory-mapped-files

I have the following test code:

```
const string filePath = @"c:\tests\mmap.bin";
const long k64 = 64 * 1024;

// create mmap file and accessor, then adquire pointer 
var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite);
fileStream.SetLength(k64);

var mmap = MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile(fileStream, null, fileStream.Length,
    MemoryMappedFileAccess.ReadWrite,
    null, HandleInheritability.None, true);

var accessor = mmap.CreateViewAccessor(0, 0, MemoryMappedFileAccess.ReadWrite);
byte* pointer = null;
accessor.SafeMemoryMappedViewHandle.AcquirePointer(ref pointer);


// dispose accessor,  mmap file and stream
accessor.SafeMemoryMappedViewHandle.Close();
accessor.Dispose();
mmap.SafeMemoryMappedFileHandle.Close();
mmap.Dispose();
fileStream.Dispose();

// This causes UnauthorizedAccessException: 
// Access to the path 'c:\tests\mmap.bin' is denied
File.Delete(filePath);
```

It creates or opens `c:\tests\mmap.bin`, set its length to 64Kb, memory maps it, and then tries to release all resources. But not all resources are released, `File.Delete(filePath)` fails.

Which is the correct way to release all resources held by memory mapped files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After

```
accessor.SafeMemoryMappedViewHandle.AcquirePointer(ref pointer);
```

you need to call

```
accessor.SafeMemoryMappedViewHandle.ReleasePointer();
```

for cleanup.

Comment: Thank you. I'm blind today.